# Sort values in python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am using python (jupyter notebook) for some analysis. I would like to sort my values in my panda data frame by the function sort_values(). First it looked like it was working correctly, however it is only working for sorting digits with 2 characters (see figure). What could I do to sort the values correctly for countries > 99?

[image]

Comment: You need convert to `int` first, `df4 = df4.astype(int)`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Please do not add code as images, add them as text and mark them as code (by selecting the whole code and pressing Ctrl+K or the `{}` button in the toolbar). Otherwise answerers need to manually type any code they need from you, instead of being able to copy & paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem values are `string`s, so lexicographically sorting.

So need first convert to numeric:

```
df4 = df4.astype(int)
```

**Sample**:

```
df4 = pd.Series(['102','11','10','10', '119', '14'])
print (df4)
0    102
1     11
2     10
3     10
4    119
5     14
dtype: object

print (df4.sort_values())
2     10
3     10
0    102
1     11
4    119
5     14
dtype: object

df4 = df4.astype(int)
print (df4.sort_values())
2     10
3     10
1     11
5     14
0    102
4    119
dtype: int32
```